# How can I solve error 403 (Forbidden) after deploying ADF Application without any security configuration?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

Friends, I need help!

I have a server with Oracle Linux 6.3.

I read this article about install & configure WebLogic Server to run ADF 11g Applications:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jdeveloper/howto/11114/managedserver/wlsadfms.html

Everything is ok.

After that, on my desktop I created very simple ADF application on JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 from this article:

http://infotechinspiration.blogspot.ru/2011/08/in-this-post-i-will-show-you-how-to.html

This ADF application successfully deployed and run when I using integrated WebLogic server in JDeveloper.

After that I successfully deployed this ADF on standalone WebLogic Server:

```
[11:04:06 AM] ---- Deployment started. ----
[11:04:06 AM] Target platform is (Weblogic 10.3).
[11:04:11 AM] Retrieving existing application information
[11:04:12 AM] Running dependency analysis...
[11:04:12 AM] Building...
[11:04:14 AM] Deploying 2 profiles...
[11:04:14 AM] Wrote Web Application Module to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\MyFirsADFpp\ViewController\deploy\MyFirsADFpp_ViewController_webapp1.war
[11:04:14 AM] Wrote Enterprise Application Module to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\MyFirsADFpp\deploy\MyFirsADFpp_application1.ear
[11:04:14 AM] Deploying Application...
[11:04:16 AM] [Deployer:149191]Operation 'deploy' on application 'MyFirsADFpp_application1' is initializing on 'ADFServer'
[11:04:21 AM] [Deployer:149192]Operation 'deploy' on application 'MyFirsADFpp_application1' is in progress on 'ADFServer'
[11:04:29 AM] [Deployer:149194]Operation 'deploy' on application 'MyFirsADFpp_application1' has succeeded on 'ADFServer'
[11:04:29 AM] Application Deployed Successfully.
[11:04:29 AM] The following URL context root(s) were defined and can be used as a starting point to test your application:
[11:04:29 AM] http://10.10.10.111:7003/MyFirsADFpp-ViewController-context-root
[11:04:29 AM] Elapsed time for deployment: 23 seconds
[11:04:29 AM] ---- Deployment finished. ----
```

I haven't any security configuration..

So, when I try to run this ADF `(http://10.10.10.111:7003/MyFirsADFpp-ViewController-context-root)` 
I’ve received an error:

```
Error 403--Forbidden 

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.4 403 Forbidden

The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.
```

I suppose, this error arise from ADF Securiy. But I really don’t know and understand how to solve this problem…
Can someone help me with it, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some question up front. Have you installed the adf runtime 11.1.1.7.0 on your stand alone server?

The doc you are referring to is for 11.1.1.4.0.

Assuming you installed the right runtime, the url you are using is wrong. You only have used the context root but have not started a task flow. If you followed the sample from the link you have to add `/faces/Employees.jspx` to the url resulting in

```
http://10.10.10.111:7003/MyFirsADFpp-ViewController-context-root/faces/Employees.jspx
```

Timo

Comment: Hi,Timo! I've installed the ADF Runtime with version 11.1.1.4.0. Now I've installed JDeveloper with the same version. Deployed ADF on Standalone WebLogic successfuly. And now try start it again: (http://10.10.10.111:7003/MyFistADFApp-ViewController-context-root/faces/Employee). Now I haven't any error..just blank page with running java process on my Oracle Linux server..

Comment: You have to check the server log. There is either an error in there out the url is wrong.

Comment: I saw in log file: ADFContext is not setup to process messages for this exception. Use the exception stack trace and error code to investigate the root cause of this exception. Root cause error code is JBO-26061 ..ORA-01005.. I found that I need to change setDomainEnv.sh in section EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES add -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true; restart WebLogic Server and it's not help.. http://10.10.10.111:7003/MyFistADFApp-ViewController-context-root/faces/Employee..blank page(